# How can I get the hosts running a certain role from within that role

Tags: ansible, ansible-role

I'm trying to setup a Zookeeper cluster and in order to set the url that points to the ZK nodes I would like to know which are the ip addresses of the hosts running the current role.

I know that from the playbook I can pass the hosts machines through a variable but it would be nice to check this within the role.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in the IP the host that is currently executing the role has, just use the builtin ansible fact for that, e.g. :

```
- debug:
    var={{ "ansible_default_ipv4['address'] }}"
```

Comment: Well, I'm interested on all the hosts running that role

Comment: This is not the way ansible works. You can imagine a role as a script running on every single host of your playbook (usually in parallel). There is no connection.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Ansible supplies a variable to access the hosts that a **role** is being applied to.  If you want to get the active hosts in the current play, use `ansible_play_hosts` (or `play_hosts` if your ansible version < 2.2).

However, I think a better solution would be to group your zookeeper nodes together in your inventory.

```
[zookeeper_nodes]
node1
node2
node3
```

From there you can access variables from those hosts using `groups` and `hostvars`

```
{% for host in groups['zookeeper_nodes'] %}
{{ hostvars[host]['ansible_eth0']['ipv4']['address'] }}
{% endfor %}
```

See [Ansible's docs on magic variables](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_variables.html#magic-variables-and-how-to-access-information-about-other-hosts) for more info.